# css have a border with padding around

Tags: css

I want to create a button as close to this image attached, with the border and a clear separation between it and the input box. Is this possible with css?

[image]

Comment: Please share your HTML/CSS that you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way to accomplish this:

```css
label {
  border: 2px solid tan;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  background: tan;
  border: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input />
</label>
```